# What is BufferedGeometry

Tags: three.js

Could someone please explain to me what BufferedGeometry is in the context of three? How is it different from normal geometry. Arn't they making the same calls to the graphics card? Also, would using BufferedGeometry be a speed improvement when making a terrain solution. At the moment I have created a terrain solution that uses hundreds of little meshes placed next to each other. This method was a slight improvement in speed compared with using a single PlaneGeometry object (presumably because mip mapping and culling can be applied more readily). However its still not great and the performance gets jerky on big landscapes - I was wondering if I should pursue BufferedGeometry or just accept the solution I have right now and limit it to small maps?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buffered geometry is a different way of sending data down to the gpu. Yes it is a speed improvement so you can give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Geometry looks something like this

```
class Geometry {

   this.vertices = []; //javascript array
   this.faces = [];    //another javascript array
   this.uvs = [];
   ...
}
```

its just a JS class

these arrays contain some complicated stuff, other classes and structures.

`this.vertices[0]` will be a `THREE.Vector3` which is another class - has data and methods, but the data is just three floats, so its pretty simple. Could have been an array [x,y,z] instead of an object with members, but then you wouldn't have the methods along with it.

`this.faces[0]` is more complicated. It holds indecis into vertices, which makes a triangle (a,b,c), but it also can hold stuff like face normal (another vec3), a tangent, a binormal, per face color etc etc.

In three, this is also where vertexNormals are stored.

WebGL has no idea how to interpret any of this stuff. It understand typedArrays, so in order to even start working with Geometry on the GPU it needs to be converted to a WebGL friendly format.

This is what BufferGeometry is. It's the same data, organized in a different way that is more low-level gpu friendly.

There are no javascript classes, no methods, no references. You have to be aware of how these arrays are filled and manage offsets and sizes.

Three JS objects `THREE.Vector3` turn into one `Float32Array(9)` [xyzxyzxyz]. 
Face doesn't have room to store all that stuff, it's just another order in another array:

Uint16Array(3) [0,1,2] (meaning: make a triangle out of vertices 0 , 1 and 2, meaning, look up into that vertex array at offsets 0 * 3 , 1 * 3 and 2 * 3.

This is the jist of it. Faster, less memory, less flexible.

If you are going to manipulate your terrain with shaders, you should use bufferGeometry. If you want to do lookups like "find nearest neighbor to this triangle, or this vertex" you are most likely going to need structure, so you either build something yourself or use `Geometry`.